# What has happened to my VS2017 Intellisense

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Something has happened to my VS2017 VB intellisense.  Whenever I enter a '.' expecting the intellisense to kick in for the current item of code, I get a whole ream of items which are not relevant to the element of code currently being constructed.  For instance when I am working with the Timeout parameters for the Threading.Timer class intellisense pops up with a list of items beginning as:

```
 adoAccess
 adoAddExpression
 adoAddRelation
 etc...
```

The correct parameter selections are listed, they are just buried within a whole ream of irrelevant other items.  Anyone else experienced this issue?  If so do you know how I can get my 'sane' intellisense back?  In an effort to get things back to normal, in case I have inadvertently made a weird options selection, I have carried out a settings reset, but to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

Open [Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-all-languages?view=vs-2017), then uncheck and recheck all checkboxes under 'Statement completion'.
[image]